# Checkbox drawable not toggled when using .isChecked = true / setChecked(true)

Tags: android, android-view, android-checkbox

I'll get right to the **question**: Is there a known issue or code that leads to the drawable of checkboxes (or other views) to not be refreshed/updated properly according to their state? If so, is there a solution?

**Setup:** I have an activity which adds a fragment containing checkboxes. The checkboxes behave peachy, responding on click events and I can handle them inside an onCheckedChangeListener. When the user has ticked three checkboxes the fragment is saved in the backstack and replaced by the subsequent fragment.

**Expected Behaviour:** If the user were to return to the previous "checkbox"-fragment, correct boxes should be ticked. CheckState of those said boxes should therefore be true so `checkbox.isChecked = true` is called in onViewCreated.

**Behaviour**: The boxes are **not** shown as ticked but behave in that manner when moving back to the previous fragment. The drawable shown is representing `checked = false` + `pressed false`

1. When I press one of the said boxes it shows the drawable representing `checked = true` + `pressed = true` and then returns to drawable representing `checked = false` + `pressed = false` on the first press, leading me to suspect that they in fact are checked as expected but shown as `checked = false`.
2. If I click on the same box again it gets checked, which supports the suspicion.
3. The "isChecked" inside the onCheckedChangeListener supports this suspicion as well being false @ #1 and true @ #2

**What I've done:** I've tried to isolate the setup in another application and everything works as expected there. I can call ".isChecked = true" in onViewCreated and those checkboxes will appear with drawable representing `checked = true`. One would think that the root of the problem would be easy to find when I've stripped the fragment down to the bare minimum but still, no luck.

Feel free to ask clarifying questions. I've been stuck on this for hours so any help is appreciated!

**Fragment:**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CompoundButton
import co.joyship.android.R
import co.joyship.android.base.BaseFragment
import co.joyship.android.co.joyship.android.constants.Screen
import co.joyship.android.data.enums.Interest
import co.joyship.android.data.enums.Interest.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_top_interests.*
import java.util.*


class InterestFragment : BaseFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var listOfInterests = ArrayList<String>()

    private var mListener: PreferencesRegistrationInterface? = null
    private var checkAccumulator: Int = 0
    private var interestViewMap = mapOf<Interest, AppCompatCheckBox>()
    private var viewInterestMap = mapOf<Int, Interest>()
    private lateinit var mOnCheckedListener: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        checkBoxesInitially()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_interests, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mOnCheckedListener = instantiateOnCheckedListener()
        generateViewMap()
        generateInterestMap()

        btnTopInterestsBack?.setOnClickListener(this)
        btnTopInterestsForward?.setOnClickListener(this)

        btnTopInterestsForward?.isEnabled = false
    }

    private fun generateViewMap() {
        interestViewMap = mapOf<Interest, AppCompatCheckBox>(
                Pair(MUSIC, cbMusic),
                Pair(TV_SERIES, cbTv),
                Pair(MOVIES, cbMovies),
                Pair(GAMES, cbGames),
                Pair(READING, cbReading),
                Pair(TRAVEL, cbTravel),
                Pair(SPORTS, cbSports),
                Pair(EXERCISE, cbExercise),
                Pair(PARTY, cbParty),
                Pair(FOOD_BEVERAGE, cbFood),
                Pair(FASHION, cbFashion),
                Pair(POLITICS, cbPolitics),
                Pair(BUSINESS, cbBusiness),
                Pair(TECHNOLOGY, cbTechnology),
                Pair(SCIENCE, cbScience))
    }

    private fun generateInterestMap() {
        viewInterestMap = mapOf(
                Pair(cbMusic.id, MUSIC),
                Pair(cbTv.id, TV_SERIES),
                Pair(cbMovies.id, MOVIES),
                Pair(cbGames.id, GAMES),
                Pair(cbReading.id, READING),
                Pair(cbTravel.id, TRAVEL),
                Pair(cbSports.id, SPORTS),
                Pair(cbExercise.id, EXERCISE),
                Pair(cbParty.id, PARTY),
                Pair(cbFood.id, FOOD_BEVERAGE),
                Pair(cbFashion.id, FASHION),
                Pair(cbPolitics.id, POLITICS),
                Pair(cbBusiness.id, BUSINESS),
                Pair(cbTechnology.id, TECHNOLOGY),
                Pair(cbScience.id, SCIENCE))
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {

        if (!clickThrottled())
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.btnTopInterestsForward -> saveInterestsAndMoveForward()
            R.id.btnTopInterestsBack ->
                mListener?.onInterestsSelectionFragmentInteraction(
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        view)
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(activityContext: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(activityContext)
        if (activityContext is PreferencesRegistrationInterface) {
            mListener = activityContext
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(activityContext!!.toString() + " must implement PreferencesRegistrationInterface")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        mListener = null
        super.onDetach()
    }


    private fun countCheck(isChecked: Boolean) {
        checkAccumulator += if (isChecked) 1 else -1
    }

    private fun checkBoxesInitially() {
        for (i in listOfInterests.indices) {
            interestViewMap
                    .filterKeys { it.toString() == listOfInterests[i] }
                    .values
                    .first().isChecked = true
        }
        checkAccumulator = listOfInterests.size
        interestViewMap.values.forEach { it.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnCheckedListener) }
    }

    private fun instantiateOnCheckedListener() =
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->


                val boxId = buttonView.id
                if (!clickThrottled()) {
                    countCheck(isChecked)

                    if (checkAccumulator <= 3) {
                        btnTopInterestsForward?.isEnabled = false


                        if (isChecked)
                            listOfInterests.add(viewInterestMap[boxId].toString())
                        else listOfInterests.remove(viewInterestMap[boxId].toString())
                    }

                    if (checkAccumulator == 3 && isChecked) {
                        saveInterestsAndMoveForward()
                    } else if (checkAccumulator > 3) {
                        btnTopInterestsForward!!.isEnabled = true
                        buttonView.isChecked = !isChecked
                        checkAccumulator--
                    }
                    btnTopInterestsForward!!.isEnabled = checkAccumulator == 3

                } else {
                    (buttonView as AppCompatCheckBox).apply {
                        setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
                        setChecked(!isChecked)
                        setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnCheckedListener)
                    }
                }
            }


    private fun saveInterestsAndMoveForward() {

        val interest1 = listOfInterests[0]
        val interest2 = listOfInterests[1]
        val interest3 = listOfInterests[2]
        mListener?.onInterestsSelectionFragmentInteraction(interest1, interest2, interest3, null)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): InterestFragment {
            return InterestFragment().apply { type = "Interest fragment" }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/svInterests"
style="@style/joyship_page.scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/joyship_background"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/marginMainMinusShadow"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorBrand">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTopInterestsBack"
        style="@style/joyship_clickableIconPadded"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconArrowNarrowEnlarged"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ib_arrow_backward" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTopInterestsForward"
        style="@style/joyship_clickableIconPadded"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconArrowNarrowEnlarged"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ib_arrow_forward" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeaderTopActivities"
        style="@style/joyship_text.header"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/halfMainMargin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/josefin_sans_regular"
        android:text="@string/headerInterestSelection"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontSizeXl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnTopInterestsBack"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        style="@style/joyship_viewgroup.card"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginBeneathOnboardingHeaderShadow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvHeaderTopActivities">


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbMusic"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/halfMainMargin"
            android:text="@string/interest_music" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbTv"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_tv" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbMovies"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_movies" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbGames"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_games" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbReading"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_reading" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbTravel"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_travel" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSports"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_sports" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbExercise"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_exercise" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbParty"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_party" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbFood"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_foodAndBeverage" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbFashion"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_fashion" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbPolitics"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_politics" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbBusiness"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_business" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbTechnology"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:text="@string/interest_technology" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbScience"
            style="@style/joyship_control.checkbox"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/halfMainMargin"
            android:text="@string/interest_science" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<style name="joyship_control">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/marginMainPlusShadow</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/marginMainPlusShadow</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/josefin_sans_regular</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fontSizeM</item>
</style>

<style name="joyship_control.checkbox" parent="joyship_control">
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/controllerHeight</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableEnd">@drawable/cb_joyship</item>
</style>
```

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... @EdgarKhimich